# WooCommerce functions for dropdown boxes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am not a wordpress developer and I am trying to piece in a small function on a woocommerce checkout function. What I need is two fold. The first is the ability to drop in a simple function that allows for a drop down box on the checkout page. I did manage to find this code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>'.__('Purchase Extra').'</h2>';

woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
    'placeholder'       => __('Enter something'),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));

echo '</div>';

}
```

And woocommerces docs say you can add the drop down like this:

```
$fields['billing']['your_field']['options'] = array(
       'option_1' => 'Option 1 text',
       'option_2' => 'Option 2 text'
  );
```

I do not know how to merge the two together.

How to extract that selection after the checkout was successful?

===========================================
I've tried the new code and while everything seems
to be working ok - the value of the selection isn't
being saved to the database. It's just blank.

**Here's my update code**

```
 add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

 function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>'.__('Purchase Domain').'</h2>';

woocommerce_form_field( 'do_domain', array(
    'type'          => 'select',
    'class'         => array('chzn-drop'),
    'label'         => __('Purchase from KitKamp?'),
    'placeholder'   => __('Enter something'),
    'options'       => array(
                    'subdomain' => __('No Thank You', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'domain' => __('Yes Please', 'woocommerce' )
                )
    ), 

    $checkout->get_value( 'do_domain' ));

echo '</div>';

}


 add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

 function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if (!$_POST['do_domain'])
     $woocommerce->add_error( __('Please select your domain type.') );
 }




 add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

 function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
   if ($_POST['do_domain']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'do_domain', esc_attr($_POST['do_domain']));
 }


 add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

 function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
     echo '<p><strong>'.__('Domain Purchase').':</strong> ' . $order->order_custom_fields['do_domain'][0] . '</p>';
 }
```

Comment: Did you ever get the value to appear in the WooCommerce order using this method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good template for you to use. It also provides a 'class' parameter which will allow you to style it easily.

```
/**
 * Add the field to the checkout
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>'.__('My Field').'</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
        'placeholder'       => __('Enter something'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));

    echo '</div>';

}
```

Now this is to add the drop down

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
$fields['my_custom_checkout_field']['options'] = array(
    'label'       => __('Options', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'    => false,
    'clear'       => false,
    'type'        => 'select',
    'class'       => array('own-css-name'),
    'options'     => array(
        'option_a' => __('option a', 'woocommerce' ),
        'option_b' => __('option b', 'woocommerce' )
        )
    );

}
```

Now validate the new custom field:

```
/**
 * Process the checkout
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if (!$_POST['my_field_name'])
         $woocommerce->add_error( __('Please enter something into this new shiny field.') );
}
```

Now save the new field to the order custom fields:

```
/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ($_POST['my_field_name']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', esc_attr($_POST['my_field_name']));
}
```

And yes this will be added to the database with the rest of the order information. I think this will solve your question about extracting:

```
/**
 * Display field value on the order edition page
 **/
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('My Field').':</strong> ' . $order->order_custom_fields['My Field'][0] . '</p>';
}
```

This will add/display the new field on the admin order edition page.

Comment: cojomojo, so now i have a question for you. Will that information be stored in the database now? And if so, how can I extract that data after a transaction was successful?

Comment: @MrTechie I changed the answer quite a bit. I didn't realize (idk how, its clear) you want to add a special custom field not override an existing field. So I addressed your situation appropriately. I also added how to extract the new field from the database

Comment: cojomojo - I've updated my post above with my existing code. It's still not entering in the value of the drop down - while everything else seems to be working ok. What's missing?

Comment: @MrTechie  sorry I have been afk. do you mean that in the database the value of the drop down is missing? And by value of the drop down, you mean what the customer selected? Or the options?